# (ReactJS + Redux) Form not loading when /new is added to url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am working on a simple React/Redux/Rails project and I am having an issue loading the form. I have a Router set up which holds the routes on my App.js page

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import '../App.css';
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar'
import Home from '../components/Home'
import Games from './Games'
import GamesShow from './GamesShow';
import GameForm from './GameForm';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Navbar />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path = '/' component={Home} />
            <Route exact path = '/games' component={Games} />
            <Route exact path = '/games/:id' component={GamesShow} />
            <Route exact path = '/games/new' component={GameForm} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

There is a link on another page that goes to /games/new.

```
<Link to="/games/new" exact>Add a new Game</Link>
```

The page loads under the url, but the page is black except for the Navbar component. I should mention that I am not even trying to load a form yet, just some sample text. I am importing everything so I know my importing/exporting is not the problem.

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';

class GameForm extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div> 
                Add a new game to the List
                <form onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit}>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default GameForm
```

Things get weird when I remove new from /games/new and comment out the original games route, it will then load the GameForm Component under the url games, but then I add /new back, it stops working. Now I think that covers everything, but here is my index.js just in case.

```
  import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './containers/App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import store from './store'

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: Try removing `exact` from the Link: `<Link to="/games/new">Add a new Game</Link>`

Comment: That did not work. I am going to leave it removed though. it seems unnecessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move `'/games/new'` above `'/games/:id'`

Like so:

```
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path = '/' component={Home} />
    <Route exact path = '/games' component={Games} />
    <Route exact path = '/games/new' component={GameForm} />
    <Route exact path = '/games/:id' component={GamesShow} />
  </Switch>
```

It needs to come before the dynamic path...

Comment: That worked! Upset I did not think of that before, but pumped it worked and I understand why.